# Talend Studio Runtime

Tags: web-services, deployment, installation, esb, talend

I have installed Talend Studio for ESB and I am working on Restful web services.At first,can someone explain to me how to deploy a web service in Talend studio .Secondly, I don't find Runtime_ESBSE that contains Talend Runtime in my installation folder.

**Note** : I am working on debian environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow this link for local deployment of the webservices in the studio itself.If you are not able to find the components as per steps.I think your installation has some issue.
I would suggest you to elaborate your problem by putting your design screenshots or some error logs.
https://help.talend.com/reader/hCrOzogIwKfuR3mPf~LydA/_4Cn9SN5QNHM6DCrGEVpOA